# Calling Angular JS function inside JQuery function not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am calling a Angular JS function inside a JQuery function , but it is not working, Can anyone point out the error

Javascript function :-

I have a text field where you can add an employee email address , Based on the added email id the angular js function pulls his full name from Google Directory. In the below function i am trying to concatenate all added employee names to one String. but i am unable to call the angular JS function inside the Jquery function.

```
     (function( $ ){

       $.fn.multipleInput = function() {

         return this.each(function() {

        angular.element('#theController').scope.getFullName($input.val());
        alert(fullname);


            }

           });
```

Angular JS function :-

I have created  the below function to pull fullname from the google directory. The angular JS function make use of a service and returns the fullname of an employee.

```
     var bipin=angular.module("ui.bootstrap.demo",['ui.bootstrap']);

     bipin.controller('theController',['$scope','$q','$http','$window',     function($scope,$q,$http,$window){
     $scope.selected = '';
       $scope.email = '';
       $scope.fullName = '';

      $scope.getFullName= function(item) {
              alert();
               return $http.get('https://myservice/v1/query/'+$label)
            .then(function(response){
              return response.data.items.map(function(item){

                    $scope.fullName=item.fullName; 

               return    item.fullName;

               });
            });



          };
```

$scope.addOne=function(num){
                   var q=$q.defer() //creates a deferred object which reperesents a task which will finish in the future
                   $scope.step++;

```
               if(angular.isNumber(num)){
                  setTimeout(function(){q.resolve(num+1)},1000)
                    }else{
                    q.reject('NaN')
                       }
                return q.promise
                }

             $scope.step=0;
             $scope.myValue=0;
             $scope.promise=$scope.addOne($scope.myValue);
             $scope.promise
             .then(function(v){return $scope.addOne(v)})
             .then(function(v){return $scope.addOne(v)})
             .then(function(v){return $scope.addOne(v)})
             .then(function(v){return $scope.addOne(v)})
             .then(
               function(v){$scope.myValue=v},
               function(err){$scope.myValue=err}
                )
        }])
```

Comment: Can you include the error?

Comment: Change angular.element('#theController').scope to angular.element('#theController').scope()

Answer (score 1):

.scope is a function.  You need to change this line:

```
angular.element('#theController').scope.getFullName($input.val());
```

to this:

```
angular.element('#theController').scope().getFullName($input.val());
```

Edited to add: To return an async operation, do this...

```
$('[ng-controller="theController"]').scope().getFullName($input.val())
    .then(function(fullName) {
        alert(fullname);
     }

$scope.getFullName= function(item) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('https://myservice/v1/query/'+$label)
        .then(function(response) {
            response.data.items.map(function(item) {
                deferred.resolve(item.fullName); 
            }
        })   

    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Comment: Error Details : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFullName' of undefined

Comment: What happens if you do Console.log(angular.element('#theController').length);

Comment: I called the console.log() inside the Jquery function  it says Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined

Comment: Thanks guys it is working now i used var fullname = $('[ng-controller="theController"]').scope().getFullName($input.val());

Comment: How can i ensure that  getFullName()  is executed  before JQuery moves to next line??

Comment: You can't.  It's an async operation, which means javascript will continue to process and come back to that once it's done.  See my edit on how to do this.  BTW, that was my bad.  It should be console.log, not Console.log.  (lower case C).